# How to double-quote names with spaces in their name

Tags: linux, bash

Error: seems to be it showing up with a _ rather than a

File tree looks like:

```
.
|-- Christina Aguilera
|   |-- Back To Basics . Ain't No Other Man.mp3
```

However, script shows this:

```
.
|-- Christina Aguilera
|   |-- Back To Basics _ Ain't No Other Man.mp3
```

The Code:

```
    tag=$(tail -c 128 $path)
    song_name=$(echo "$tag" | cut -c 4-33 | sed -r 's/ +$//')
    artist_name=$(echo "$tag" | cut -c 34-63 | sed -r 's/ +$//')
    album_name=$(echo "$tag" | cut -c 64-93 | sed -r 's/ +$//')
    test -e "$2/$artist_name" || mkdir "$2/$artist_name"
    ln -s $path "$2/$artist_name/$album_name _ $song_name.mp3"
done
```

How can I edit this code to resolve the error?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your output will be shown with " `_` " and you want to replace it with a " `.` " all you need to do is replace the " `_` " with a " `.` "

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas:

- Try running your script with `bash -x script` to display debugging information.  That should show you exactly where the error occurs.
- When you write a question, include the *smallest complete snippet* that will reproduce the error, and the *exact* text of the error message.
- You commented that "it just says that it couldn't create a directory."  This sounds like the `mkdir` is failing.  Does the top-level directory (that is, whatever `$2` is) exist?  If not, use `mkdir -p "$2/$artist_name"` to create the entire path.
- A small simplification:  instead of using `sed -r 's/ +$//'` to remove spaces, you can use `tr -d ' '` instead.

Comment: i did all of this and yet  it doesnt, i am fairly new to linux is there any way u could tell me where exactly or what to put bash -x script in the coding. i got the _ to become . , by putting "." , but it still gives me the same error. error says Check the names of your directories and files.
Most of them contain spaces - remember to double-quote names with spaces in their name!

Comment: you can either run the current problem script **from the command-line** like `bash -x yourProblematicScript.sh` OR 1. change the top line to `#!/bin/bash -x` OR insert a line in your script near where you think the problem is, `set -x` ; You can turn of the 'eXpansion' with `set +x`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but it looks like the last line of the script is introducing the `_`, so just change it to a `.` there. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: yes thank u for replying. But i tried that and it just says that it couldnt create a directory. Any other options?

Comment: It looks like some parts of your code are missing. Also you have not stated what the code is supposed to do in the first place. Without further information I can't really help you, sorry.